# Trying to generate WordPress thumbnails programmatically

Tags: php, image, wordpress

I'm trying to add a bunch of posts programmatically, and then add their attendant images. I have an array with all the image filenames in it, and I've been able to add them to the database, but I can't seem to get the proper thumbnails created.

The posts are coming from a csv located in wp-content/uploads/dirname/. They have numbers in their filenames which correspond to an ID in the CSV, which is how I know what images need to be added to what post id.

I've gotten the wp_insert_attachment() part to work with the images right there in their own little directory, but I couldn't get the thumbnails to generate. I installed the regenerate thumbnails plugin, and it was able to generate them, but I can't seem to get it to happen programmatically.

I thought that might be because wp_generate_attachment needs the photos to be in /uploads/2011/12/ (e.g.), so I started down the path of moving the images and then trying to add them. This makes sense anyway because I kinda want to make copies rather than have 5 or 6 different media sizes added to my wp-content/uploads/dirname/ dir.

Anyway, it doesn't work. Moving the images via PHP's copy doesn't work, and the thumbnails don't generate.

```
foreach ($frazerfiles[$stock_num] as $stock_img){
  require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
  echo "... ...Trying to add attachment metadata...";

  // copy the file to the upload dir
  $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
  $file_to_move = ABSPATH."wp-content/uploads/".$stock_img;
  if (copy($file_to_move, $uploads['path']."/")) {
    echo "Moved $file_to_move to ".$uploads['path']."/";
    $my_moved_file = $uploads['path']."/".$stock_img;

    // I think this is failing because the images aren't in the upload dir.
    $attachment = array(
       'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
       'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($stock_img)),
       'post_content' => '',
       'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    if ($attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $my_moved_file, $newpostid )) {
      if ($attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $my_moved_file)) {
        echo "...success for $my_moved_file: ID:$attach_id<br />\n";
      } else {
        echo "...FAILED for $my_moved_file ID:$attach_id<br />\n";
        print_r($attach_data);
      }
    } else { // inserting attachment failed
      echo "Insert attachment failed for $my_moved_file to $newpostid<br />\n"; 
    }
  } else {
    echo "Failed moving $file_to_move to ".$uploads['path']."/";
  }


}// images foreach
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After cross checking with WordPress core files, the only thing that seems to be missing out is `wp_update_attachment_metadata` immediately after `wp_generate_attachment_metadata`.

Try adding

```
wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
```

after

```
echo "...success for $my_moved_file: ID:$attach_id<br />\n";
```

So the if block looks like

```
 if ($attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $my_moved_file)) {
    echo "...success for $my_moved_file: ID:$attach_id<br />\n";
    wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
  } else {
    echo "...FAILED for $my_moved_file ID:$attach_id<br />\n";
    print_r($attach_data);
  }
```

**Suggestion:** (not related to the question)

move the line

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
```

outside(above) the for loop.

UPDATE 1:
Adding suggestion to fix the copy issue.
You missed out the "check the file type" line.
(PHP copy function will fail if the destination file(`$my_moved_file`) already exists)

Change this code

```
// copy the file to the upload dir
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
$file_to_move = ABSPATH."wp-content/uploads/".$stock_img;
if (copy($file_to_move, $uploads['path']."/")) {
echo "Moved $file_to_move to ".$uploads['path']."/";
$my_moved_file = $uploads['path']."/".$stock_img;

// I think this is failing because the images aren't in the upload dir.
$attachment = array(
   'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
   'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($stock_img)),
   'post_content' => '',
   'post_status' => 'inherit'
);
```

TO

```
// copy the file to the upload dir
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
$file_to_move = ABSPATH."wp-content/uploads/".$stock_img;
$my_moved_file = $uploads['path']."/".$stock_img;
if (copy($file_to_move, $my_moved_file)) {
    echo "Moved $file_to_move to ".$my_moved_file;

    // Check the file type
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($my_moved_file), null );

    $attachment = array(
       'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
       'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($my_moved_file)),
       'post_content' => '',
       'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
```

Comment: Hm, you're right. Thanks for the suggestion. Still, the copy part doesn't work. Any thoughts there?

Comment: Updated answer, please check after UPDATE 1:

Comment: I ended up moving the copy stuff out to a function of its own, and it works now. The problem ended up being that PHP's copy() isn't like cp from the shell, in that the second argument needs to be the filename **in its destination directory**, not merely the directory name.

so path/to/file/filename.ext not just path/to/file

Comment: Yes you are correct about copy, that's why I moved `$my_moved_file` line to above if and used it in copy function. Sorry for not explaining that.